# Can you evaluate a string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, expression-evaluation

I have a variable and I have a function stored in it as a string:

```
var x = "func myFunction(y :Int) {println(y)}"
```

Is there a way to evaluate the string and run the function?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No.

There is no equivalent of [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in JavaScript or [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) in Java for Swift.

A common use for string evaluation is mathematical expressions; if you want to evaluate these, you can use [`NSExpression.valueWithExpression(format: String)`](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/):

```
let stringWithMathematicalOperation: String = "5*5" // Example
let exp: NSExpression = NSExpression(format: stringWithMathematicalOperation)
let result: Double = exp.expressionValue(with:nil, context: nil) as! Double // 25.0
```

Comment: This does crash when you perform mod operation. 10%20 it will crash.

Comment: I am trying to use that for formulas, but when I divide multiply and power it gives me a strange number that don’t correspond to the correct result

Comment: My problem was related with the comma format, after change it everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if string contains boolean expression then also this can be evaluated. I've done it something like this,

```
let stringWithMathematicalOperation: String = "true && false "
let exp: NSExpression = NSExpression(format: stringWithMathematicalOperation)
let result: Bool = exp.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as Bool // Answer: false
```